# Trying to edit containerd service (temporary file is empty)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I am editing:

```
/etc/systemd/system/containerd.service.d/override.conf
```

But received:

> canceled: temporary file is empty.

```bash
systemctl edit containerd.service
```

```
# add follows
Service
KillMode=
KillMode=mixed
```

Comment: Hello Erwan, welcome to SO, can you please edit this question to add more details and be more specific of the problem? We have no context of your problem, so this would be hard to answer without further details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.